# Remove css position absolute while keeping element inline

Tags: html, css

How can I accomplish this without using an absolutely positioned span?

```
<div>
 <span style="position: absolute; right: 5px;">[details]</span>
 <div style="background-color: White;">
  <span style="white-space: pre;">foo: !         Bar: ?</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

The `position: absolute;` is causing display errors and needs to be adjusted. How can change this markup to show the same as here: http://jsfiddle.net/yHHAL/ but without using `position: absolute;`? The order of the elements can change if they have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float: right` instead of your `position: absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xtzzq/

Comment: I was under the impression that `float` implicitly uses `position: absolute;`. However, this works when tested in ie8,ff,chrome, and safari so it is good enough for me.

Comment: No.  `position: absolute` removes the element from the flow of the page, similar to what `display: none` would do.  Floats tell the neighboring elements to flow around them.